# PHP: Object for HTML hyperlink

Tags: php, object

Update: I edited the code below for the class to correct an error that came up when I ran it (needed "new" to create the object). With that correction, the code runs and correctly generates the HTML. But since I'm new to OOP, I'd still like to know if I've taken the right approach.

2nd update: I address a concern about the efficiency of this technique in the addendum below. I also corrected the order of the anchor name and querystring in the URL, which are handled correctly by hLink().

---

I have a function that generates HTML for hyperlinks. It's arguments may be string literals or variables read from the database. An example call to this function looks like:

```
hLink('http://example.com', 'website', 'section', 'input=0', '_blank');
```

which returns:

```
'<a HRef="http://example.com?input=0#section" target="_blank">website</a>'
```

The first argument is required, and the remaining four have defaults.

I'm looking at replacing this function with a method defined in a class, so the function calls would be replaced with calls to that method acting on a call to the class constructor. I'm new to object-oriented programming, so I'd like to know if I'm doing this right, or even if I should be doing this at all.

The class I've come up with is:

```
class link
    {private $sURL;
     private $sText   = '';
     private $sLocn   = '';
     private $sQuery  = '';
     private $sWindow = '';
     public function __construct($sURL)
        {$this->sURL = $sURL;}
     public function sText($sText)     {$this->sText   = $sText;   return $this;}
     public function sLocn($sLocn)     {$this->sLocn   = $sLocn;   return $this;}
     public function sQuery($sQuery)   {$this->sQuery  = $sQuery;  return $this;}
     public function sWindow($sWindow) {$this->sWindow = $sWindow; return $this;}
     public function hLink()
        {...}
     }
```

where the body of method hLink() is the same as the body of the original function hLink().

With this class, the equivalent of the above function call would be:

```
(new link('http://example.com'))->sText('website')->sLocn('section')->sQuery('input=0')->sWindow('_blank')->hLink()
```

which is intended to generate the same string as before:

```
'<a HRef="http://example.com?input=0#section" target="_blank">website</a>'
```

How does this look? Am I on the right track?

---

**Addendum**

It troubled me that the above technique creates a new object for each link on the page, and that object does nothing after it is used once to create the HTML for the link. It's a small object and there won't be more than a few hundred of them on a page, so it won't be a big memory burden, but it still seems wasteful and inefficient. I have an idea for addressing this:

- In the class, have no constructor and have a method clear() that sets the values of all properties to their defaults (empty).
- Create one instance of this class.
- Place a link on the page using this object, calling the clear() method on it, then the methods that set whatever property values are needed, and finally the outputting method hLink() as before.

The code for this is as follows: (Pardon my formatting. I know it's unconventional, but I find this easier to read.)

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
$oLink = new link;
class link
    {private $sURL;
     private $sText;
     private $sAnchor;
     private $sQuery;
     private $sWindow;
     public function clear() 
        {$this->sURL    = ''; 
         $this->sText   = ''; 
         $this->sAnchor = '';
         $this->sQuery  = ''; 
         $this->sWindow = ''; 
         return $this;
         }
     public function URL(string $sURL)       {$this->sURL    = $sURL;    return $this;}
     public function text(string $sText)     {$this->sText   = $sText;   return $this;}
     public function anchor(string $sAnchor) {$this->sAnchor = $sAnchor; return $this;}
     public function query(string $sQuery)   {$this->sQuery  = $sQuery;  return $this;}
     public function window(string $sWindow) {$this->sWindow = $sWindow; return $this;}
     public function hLink()
        {return('<a HRef="' .  $this->sURL . 
                              ($this->sQuery  == '' ? '' : '?' . $this->sQuery) . 
                              ($this->sAnchor == '' ? '' : '#' . $this->sAnchor) .
                        '"' . ($this->sWindow == '' ? '' : ' target="' . $this->sWindow . '"') .
                 '>' . $this->sText. '</a>');
         }
     }
echo('Link to ' . $oLink->clear()->URL('http://example.com')->text('website')->anchor('section')->query('input=0')->window('_blank')->hLink() . ' in text');
```

I've tested the above code as a freestanding script, and it does output the intended:

```
Link to <a HRef="http://example.com?input=0#section" target="_blank">website</a> in text
```

So is this a better way? Now there's only one object that gets reused each time another link is needed on the page. Is this the best way to generate HTML for hyperlinks embedded in text in PHP?

Comment: The logic here looks fine, but I would recommend against using shortcut method names like `sLocn`. The code formatting on the other hand...

Comment: This might be better off over on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If the `s` prefix is meant to indicate it's a string variable, you may want to know that since PHP/7 you can [declare scalar arguments type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) and, in all all versions, [docblocks](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html) are standard tool that decent IDEs acknowledge.

The code format is also fairly unusual. In the end, trying to make your code compact to make better use of screen space does not really pay off: it's harder on the eyes (trust me, you'll get older) and nobody else is doing it so you can't use your editor's code format features without investing a lot of time reconfiguring it.

Other than that, I don't see anything intrinsically wrong.

Here's a quick example of basically your same code with type hints, docblocks and [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

```
class Link
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $text = '';

    /**
     * @param string $url
     */
    public function __construct(string $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $text
     * @return Link
     */
    public function text(string $text): Link
    {
        $this->text = $text;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. On your suggestion, I've now implemented strict typing in all my PHP files. As for the formatting, I do find it easier to read this way, and I'm already pretty old. I use Notepad++, not an IDE. The code is only maintained by me, so I'm concerned about functionality and efficiency, but I prefer to use a format that feels right to me. I hope it doesn't make it difficult for you to review. I've written an addendum to the question. Could you let me know what you think of that change?